# MKLocalSearch the request timed out NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, xcode8

When I do a MKLocalSearch I am getting a "request time out" error,
when running on an iPhone 6s physical device. When I run on an emulator I do not have this problem.

I am using XCode 8 IOS 10, and the free provisioning profile.
(last week I was using Xcode 7 and had no problems)
Could this be because of the new provisioning profile.

**Here is the error message:**

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 
>   "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17024c630
>   {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/dispatcher.arpc?abBranchId=18.K,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/dispatcher.arpc?abBranchId=18.K,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

**The Code:**

```
        MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                MKMapItem *firstItem = response.mapItems.firstObject;
                if (firstItem) {
                    //store in cache
                    _mapItemsDictionary[destination.destinationAddress] = firstItem;
                    handler(firstItem);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR : FirstObject from MapItems is null");
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"ERROR Could not get MAPITEM :%@",error.description);
                handler(nil);
            }
        }];
```

I have this in my plist:

> ```
> <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
> <dict>
>   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
>   <true/>
> </dict>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

After rebooting the IOS device and waiting some time (24 hours) all started
again without any code changes or Xcode Changes.

Comment: Just rebooting device worked for me (not needing wait of 24hours), cheers :)